# Can i access ValidationMessage through jquery in asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Im trying to access ValidationMessage through jquery. I have
    <%: Html.TextBox("vcr_LinkAddress",null, new { maxlength = 255 })%>
    <%: Html.ValidationMessage("vcr_LinkAddress")%>
and i want to validate textbox and if it is empty ill print a message in ValidationMessage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a look at

http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2008/09/10/asp-net-mvc-tip-43-use-data-annotation-validators.aspx

or

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410405.aspx

Answer (score 0):

so you want to integrate client-side validation (with jQuery validation) with your existing server-side validation?

if your server-side validation is using the IRulesProvider Interface i suggest that you look into xVal http://xval.codeplex.com/